# What is the use case of putting undefined into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, undefined

I am trying to see if there's any acutal use case of putting `undefined` into an array, such as

```
var test = [undefined, undefined, "1"]
```

the array will indeed have a length of 3. Why is it allow? I totally understand to have null in array, but doesn't make sense to have undefined.
Is there any actual use case to have undefined in a array?

Comment: Why wouldn't it allow this? `undefined` is what un-initialized variables are set to, but that doesn't mean that that's their sole use case.

Comment: i rephrased my question. I think my question is more toward of an actual story of putting undefined into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing purposes is one use case . If there is an undefined value in an array for one reason or another, then you may want to test your code to see how it deals with such situations.

Answer (score 0):

if you write this

```
var b;
console.log(typeof b);
```

It will show it as "undefined" (which is one of the primitive types of javascript)

if you do:

```
var arr = [];

arr.push(b);

console.log(arr)
```

It will print [undefined] which is the value assigned by javascript to variable b